# Getting a row from a data attribute in datatables.js

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am struggling trying to find the right method to do this. Basically, I have an array of id values that correspond to which rows have been selected in my table. To construct this list, I use the following code. `this.options.ajaxId` is the key that accesses my Id value in the data object passed to the table.

```
this.getRowData(target)[this.options.ajaxId]
```

where my `getRowData` function is:

```
getRowData: function (HTMLrow) {
    return this.dataTable.row(HTMLrow).data();
},
```

This works great, but then I am stumped on my next step which is re-selecting the correct rows when the table is re-drawn via paging, sorting, or searching. My plan was to cycle through the ID's and find which table row corresponded to that ID value, but I cannot find a function to input a key value search pair and return the html row. Something like the following is what I was thinking,

```
this.dataTable.findRow( key, value );
// then my usage would be the following:
var that = this;
_.each(this.selectedList, function (id) {
    var row = that.dataTable.findRow( that.options.ajaxId, id );
    // code to select the row
});
```

I haven't written it yet, but I know I can cycle through each of the rows, get the data for that row, and check it against what I am looking for, but in cases where the user is viewing 100 rows and has only one selection I would like to avoid that.

Any insight?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm thanks for the tip, that does help with retaining the paging etc, unfortunately I have added the selection mechanism manually so it isn't included in this feature

Comment: @davidkonrad I never professed to be expert at it...how does your snotty abrasive comment bring anything constructive to the situation? I made a casual suggestion was all. Does trying to help merit nasty rude ignorant comments? get a grip

Comment: So provide a solution that works , no need for cryptic remarks. I am never one to not say i was wrong

Comment: Did you have a chance to try the code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727138/3549014)?

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION #1**

You can use the following code to locate and highlight rows based on row IDs if row ID is stored in one of the fields.

```js
// Index of column containing IDs
var colIdIndex = 0;

// List of row IDs
var rowIds = ['2', '4', '6'];

// Find indexes of rows which have IDs in the desired column
var rowIndexes = table.rows().eq(0).filter( function (rowIdx) {
    return ($.inArray(table.cell( rowIdx, colIdIndex ).data(), rowIds) !== -1) 
        ? true 
        : false;
});    

// Select rows based on array of found row indexes
table.rows(rowIndexes)
    .nodes()
    .to$()
    .addClass('selected');
```

See [`filter()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/filter%28%29#Examples) API method for more details.

Please note that this method will work for client-side processing mode only.

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n46qnrwt/) for code and demonstration.

> **SOLUTION #2**

Alternative approach that would work both in client-side and server-side processing modes would be to use [`createdRow`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) callback.

For example:

```
// Index of column containing IDs
var colIdIndex = 0;

// List of row IDs
var rowIds = ['2', '4', '6'];

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        if ( $.inArray(data[colIdIndex], rowIds) !== -1) {
            $(row).addClass('selected');
        }
    }        
});
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jte11Lb1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: awesome you actually did answer :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, I couldn't pass it after you mentioned that I will answer the question.